# SASS Variables Namespacing

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

I'm creating open source select box script, and using SASS as a preprocessor for my CSS code.

My question is, should I prefix the SASS variables with unique namespace of my script, i.e.:

```
@my-plugin-border-color: 20px !default;
@my-plugin-background: 20px !default;
// e.t.c.
```

Or leave just:

```
@border-color: 20px !default;
@background: 20px !default;
// e.t.c.
```

May it cause any conflicts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating plugins it's best practice (imo) to have your css variables namespaced with the script name. This pretty much guarantees no conflicts. Flexslider is a good example.